# IndexError: string index out of range(str1[-1])

Tags: python, string

Here is my function:

```
def find_last(str1):
    return str1[-1]
```

When i run it:

```
print find_last('aaaa')
```

I have the following error:

```
return str1[-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: for `'aaaa'` that function would never raise `IndexError.` You're surely passing an empty string.

Comment: @Micheal that won't happen use the example you caused it to make happen.

Comment: yeah, maybe i have expediently pass an empty string

Comment: It runs fine for me, so perhaps it is the empty string.

Comment: @MichaelVayvala Then check the string length before indexing it or use try-except.

Comment: It runs fine for me, so I suspect you're passing an empty value. You should check if the parameter is empty or not.

Comment: Why would someone use this function when they can simply index by -1?  Also, the function would be better named `get_last` as "find" implies searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function as you have written it fails only if an empty string is passed in (or something that's not a string or other sequence, of course). A great way to make sure this works without having to check for the empty string is to use slicing rather than indexing:

```
def get_last(text):
    return text[-1:]
```

This means "return from the last character through the end." This works even on empty strings because slicing stops at either end of the string automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine:

```
>>> def find_last(str1):
...     return str1[-1]
... 
>>> print find_last('aaaa')
a
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get that response with `'aaaa'` but you could improve your function with:

```
def find_last(str1):

    return str1[-1] if str1 else None
```